# Making SWF (Flash) Banner Clickable

Tags: flash, swfobject, banner

I am using SWFobject.

I am creating Banner Management System. I need to integrate Flash (SWF) banners and need to keep track of clicks and impressions.

I tried to wrap flash object within anchor tag. Not working :)

I gone through [Best way to implement a flash website banner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243599/best-way-to-implement-a-flash-website-banner)

The first reply says that:

However, for simple things like clickable banners, all you may need is swfobject.

Can anyone tell, how to create clickable banners with swfobjects?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33459/how-do-you-use-a-flash-object-as-a-link and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444562/javascript-onclick-event-over-flash-object

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your project constraints are, I'm not sure if having the click-tracking separate from the Flash content is required. In my experience most click-tracking on banners is handled within the Flash content. So most agencies producing banners will either have a Flash-based template for banners that include all the code to report clicks, or a Flash wrapper that loads banners into it and tracks clicks.

swfobject, as far as I know, is just used to display Flash consistently across browsers, there is no way to use swfobject as a click-tracking device.

You may be able to implement a javascript solution though, wrapping the swfobject embed in another javascript wrapper that is able to track clicks for you. The benefit with using flash though is that you can track where the user clicked, or even where they hovered over objects and for how long.